# rebuild array based on value found inside

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following array

```
[
  {
    "dn": "cn=GAU200900LD01,cn=Workstations,ou=200900,ou=GAU,o=firstrand,c=za",
    "name": "GAU200900LD01",
    "mac_address": "00:24:1D:AF:D2:84",
    "address": "10.34.102.2",
    "image": "scImageFile=FNBSALES,cn=default,cn=global,o=firstrand,c=za"
  },
  {
    "dn": "cn=GAU200900LD02,cn=Workstations,ou=200900,ou=GAU,o=firstrand,c=za",
    "name": "GAU200900LD02",
    "mac_address": "00:24:1D:AF:D2:23",
    "address": "10.34.102.3",
    "image": "scImageFile=FNBSALES,cn=default,cn=global,o=firstrand,c=za"
  },
  {
    "dn": "cn=GAU200900LD03,cn=Workstations,ou=200900,ou=GAU,o=firstrand,c=za",
    "name": "GAU200900LD03",
    "mac_address": "00:24:1D:AF:DB:8B",
    "address": "10.34.102.4",
    "image": "scImageFile=FNBSALES,cn=default,cn=global,o=firstrand,c=za"
  },
  {
    "dn": "cn=GAU555555LD01,cn=Workstations,ou=555555,ou=GAU,o=firstrand,c=za",
    "name": "GAU555555LD01",
    "mac_address": "00:00:00:00:00:00",
    "address": "10.0.0.2",
    "image": "cn=Ubuntu,cn=default,cn=global,o=firstrand,c=za"
  }
]
```

I am trying to strip out all objects where a the ou value does not match a specific value eg. ou=200900. So I do not want to have my array contain the object where the ou=555555

Comment: You will have to parse the array.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I recommend learning regex for effective parsing

Comment: ok thanks let me try it

Comment: You can start by looking at ‘Array.prototype.filter’ method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the functionality with indexOf and filter like:

const result = objects.filter(object => object.dn.indexOf('200900') > 0);

const result = objects.filter(object => object.dn.indexOf('ou=200900') > 0);

```
console.log(result);
```

Comment: use indexOf("ou=200900,") (ends in ",", else ou=200900 and ou=2009002 match)

Comment: Thanks this gets me closer